# My text file won't read and display on the DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, text-files, streamreader

```
private void write(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FileStream outputFileStream = new FileStream("test.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outputFileStream);
    Random r = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; j++)
        {
            double d = 0;
            Double.TryParse(Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value), out d);

            writer.Write(d + "\t");
        }
        writer.Write("\n");
    }

    writer.Close();
    outputFileStream.Close();
}
```

So this is the method to write the text file. It works fine because I have opened it successfully with an Excel. I even tried to copy and paste it and it would work. Now the problem is.....

```
private void read(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    char TAB = '\t';
    char NEWLINE = '\n';

    FileStream inputFileStream = new FileStream("test.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(inputFileStream);

    string line;
    string[] fields;

    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; j++)
        {
            line = reader.ReadLine();
            fields = line.Split(TAB, NEWLINE);
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = fields;
        }
    }
    inputFileStream.Close();
    reader.Close();
}
```

However when I read the file back onto a DataGridView it does not work properly. Now this is the exact text file that I wrote on my code. Instead what happens is that it is displayed on only 1 row. How do I get back the amount of columns and rows from what the user entered? I prefer keeping it a text file.

I have used default properties for my `dataGridView1`

Comment: you should consider using a Database or xml :)

Comment: @Selman22 I don't have Access installed on my machines. And I'm not really sure on how to use SQL related things. I just find text file easier. XML I've never tried either.

Comment: before your read method, datagridview is empty right ?

Comment: @Selman22: All the properties of the datagrid are default. I dont know if it's considered empty when it runs from start, since I see 1 row with nothing on it.

Comment: You should clear `dataGridView1` on your `read` method, then add new rows and columns as you read the file.

Comment: @puretppc okey, I was wondering that exactly =)

Comment: @puretppc take a look at my answer,if you get any error let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`RowCount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowcount%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns displayed rows count. So here it returns 1 because you are displaying one row and it's empty:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
```

Instead of this, you should create new rows and add it to the Rows collection like this:

```
// Use File.ReadAllLines, it's easier
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("test.txt");

foreach(line in lines)
{
   var text = line.Split('\t','\n');
   dataGridView1.Rows.Add(text);
}
```

Comment: It actually works. I also added in `dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();` just so it can reset it back. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("yourfile.txt");
string[] columnnames = file.ReadLine().Split(' ');
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

foreach (string c in columnnames)
{
    dt.Columns.Add(c);
}
string newline;
while ((newline = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    string[] values = newline.Split(' ');
    for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
    {
        dr[i] = values[i];
    }
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
file.Close();
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

try this one with your own **delimiters** i.e. *\t* and \n. And First try to search your problems on internet before posting queries and try to solve them by yourself. I am not giving full code.